# Solid State Drive not in the drive disk

Tags: dell, ssd

I have a **DELL Inspiron 15 3000** and, when i am in the Installation Type windows, I just see my USB stick and not my SSD in the devices.

How can i install elementary on my SSD ?

Thx for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Precision 7530 that had the same issue. I had to go into the UEFI/BIOS and change the SATA settings from RAID to AHCI, even though I'm using an M.2 NVMe drive. Once I made that change and rebooted into the installation USB I was able to see the SSD and install the OS. Changing from RAID to AHCI may not allow you to boot into your Windows installation.